# PythonCard not getting 'enter' KeyEvent in Windows

Tags: windows, wxpython, keyevent, keycode, pythoncard

I'm sorry if this is a newbie question, but I am writing a PythonCard program and I want it to do something when I press the enter key from inside a TextBox. My code is below:

```
def on_SampleTextField_keyDown(self, event):
    if event.keyCode == wx.WXK_RETURN:
        doSomething()
    else:
        event.Skip()
```

This works fine on Linux, but when I run it on Windows it just acts as the Tab key would. After searching the web I believe Windows is treating the enter key as a navigational key, and if I were using just wxPython I would need to set the window style to wx.WANTS_CHARS . I think this should be possible in PythonCard since it just sits on top of wxPython, but I'm not sure. And if it is I wouldn't know how to do it! So if anyone has any ideas, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wxPython I was able to use the return key when adding `wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER` to the style of the `TextCtrl` and binding the `wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER` event as described [here](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Catching_key_events_globally).
PythonCard neither defines this event nor can you manually alter the style of the TextField since this property is set in `__init__()`. Another option that worked for me in wxPython was binding to the `wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK` event which does not require a certain style attribute to be set during initialisation. That's why I used this approach to come up with a somewhat hacky solution to the problem.

PythonCard defines its events in class structures like this:

```
class KeyPressEvent(KeyEvent):    
    name = 'keyPress'
    binding = wx.EVT_CHAR
    id = wx.wxEVT_CHAR
```

I used this structure as a template for a new custom event so my code now looks something like this:

```
from PythonCard import model
from PythonCard.event import KeyEvent
import PythonCard.components.textfield

import wx

class KeyPressHookEvent(KeyEvent):    
    name = 'keyPressHook'
    binding = wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK
    id = wx.wxEVT_CHAR_HOOK

# TextFieldEvents is a tuple so type juggling is needed to modify it
PythonCard.components.textfield.TextFieldEvents = tuple(
        list(PythonCard.components.textfield.TextFieldEvents) + 
        [KeyPressHookEvent])
```

Then I create my application as usual and define the handler:

```
def on_keyPressHook(self, event):
    if event.keyCode == wx.WXK_RETURN:
        self.handle_return()
    else:
        event.Skip()
```

That way I can handle the press of the return key in `handle_return()`. This works on Windows, but not in Cygwin and so maybe not on linux. At least in Cygwin the application still receives the press of the return key in `on_keyDown()` so all you have to do is to copy the content of `on_keyPressHook()` to that function.